# arrays in arrays weird thing? Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a variable `B` that stores how many user objects have been added in the array `userarr`. I'm using one line of code that adds a note that the user types in to the `B` element user object in the `userarr` array. Here it is:

```
userarr[login].notes[b] = tempnote;
```

`tempnote` is a string variable that temporarily holds the note the user types in, and `login` stores the user number that you are logged in to. So it assigns the string variable `tempnote` to the `login` value user object in the `user` array, and in element `b` element in the notes array for that user.

But for some reason there is a problem with this line of code.
I know it is that line of code, because it happens right after you confirm you want to add that note, and there is a `println` right next to it that never appears.

Here is the method for the whole note thing:

```
 public static void loggedin() {
     System.out.println("welcome, " + userarr[login].username + "!");
     do{
         System.out.println("type 'notes' to list current notes, type 'new' to add notes, type 'delete' to delete a note, or type 'exit' to exit the program.");
         switch(scan.nextLine()){
             case "exit":
                 System.out.println("exiting");
                 login = -1;
                 break;
              case "delete":

                 break;
              case "new":
                 System.out.println("\n\nType the note.");
                 String tempnote = scan.nextLine();
                 System.out.println("note is is now " + tempnote + ". is this what you want? type 'yes' to proceed, or 'no' to enter note again.");
                 String ch5 = scan.nextLine();
                 if (ch5.equals("no")) {
                     break;
                 } else {
                    userarr[login].notes[b] = tempnote;
                    System.out.println("note created!");
                    b += 1;
                 }
                 break;
             case "notes":
                 for (int i=0;i<b;i++) {
                     System.out.println("Note " + i + ":");
                     System.out.println(userarr[login].notes[i] + "\n");
                 }
                 break;
             default: 
                 System.out.println("restarting.");

         };
     }while(login != -1);
}
```

Here is the user object thing:

```
 static class user extends TextGame {
     String username;
     int password;
     String[] notes;

     public user(String username, int password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
     }

 }
 static user[] userarr = new user[10];
 static int a = 0;
 static int b = 0;
 static int login = -1;
```

There is no error before i run it. when i get to the part that has the problem it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at text.game.TextGame.loggedin(TextGame.java:80)
at text.game.TextGame.login(TextGame.java:53)
at text.game.TextGame.main(TextGame.java:135)
```

anyone know the problem?

EDIT: It seems necessary to show the whole class, because there is apparently a lot more information people need to know. So here is the whole thing for you to have all the information you need:

```
package text.game;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextGame {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static class user extends TextGame {
        String username;
        int password;
        String[] notes;

        public user(String username, int password) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }

     }
     static user[] userarr = new user[10];
     static int a = 0;
     static int b = 0;
     static int login = -1;


     public static void newuser() {
         System.out.println("\n\nType the username for this user.");
         String usernameA = scan.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Username is now " + usernameA + ". is this what you want? type 'yes' to proceed, or 'no' to enter username again.");
         if (scan.nextLine().equals("no")) {
             newuser();
         } else {
             System.out.println("\n\n type the password for this user. (numbers only.)");
             int passwordA = scan.nextInt();
             System.out.println("user is " + usernameA + " and password is " + passwordA + ". creating user.");
             userarr[a] = new user(usernameA, passwordA);
             System.out.println("user created!");
             a += 1;
         }
     }

     public static void login() {
         System.out.println("which account do you want to log into? type the name of a user, or type 'list' to view the users signed in.");
         String ch2 = scan.nextLine();
         if (ch2.equals("list")){
             for (int i=0;i<a;i++) {
                 System.out.println(userarr[i].username);
             }
         } else {
             for (int i=0;i<a;i++) {if ((userarr[i].username).equals(ch2)){
                  System.out.println("type the password for this account (USE NUMBERS ONLY).");
                  int ch4 = scan.nextInt();
                  if (ch4==userarr[i].password) {
                      System.out.println("logged in!"); login = i; loggedin();
                  }else{
                      System.out.print("incorrect password!");
                  }
             }
         }
     }
 }

 public static void loggedin() {
     System.out.println("welcome, " + userarr[login].username + "!");
     do{
         System.out.println("type 'notes' to list current notes, type 'new' to add notes, type 'delete' to delete a note, or type 'exit' to exit the program.");
         switch(scan.nextLine()){
             case "exit":
                 System.out.println("exiting");
                 login = -1;
                 break;
             case "delete":

                 break;
             case "new":
                 System.out.println("\n\nType the note.");
                 String tempnote = scan.nextLine();
                 System.out.println("note is is now " + tempnote + ". is this what you want? type 'yes' to proceed, or 'no' to enter note again.");
                String ch5 = scan.nextLine();
                if (ch5.equals("no")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    userarr[login].notes[b] = tempnote;
                    System.out.println("note created!");
                    b += 1;
                }
                break;
            case "notes":
                for (int i=0;i<b;i++) {
                    System.out.println("Note " + i + ":");
                    System.out.println(userarr[login].notes[i] + "\n");
                }
                break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("restarting.");

        };
    }while(login != -1);
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     do {
         System.out.println("Welcome to LINCOLN COMP console OS. Type 'new' to create a new user, type 'log' to log in to an existing user, or type 'exit' to leave.\nif you are asked a yes or no question, if you type something other than yes or no, it will default to yes.");
         String ch1 = scan.nextLine();
         switch (ch1) {
             case "new":
                 if (a==2) {
                     System.out.println("maximum users have been created. type a username to delete that user, type list to list users, or type back to return.");
                     String ch3 = scan.nextLine();
                     if (ch3.equals("list")) {
                         for (int i=0;i<a;i++) { 
                              if (userarr[i].username==null) {
                                  System.out.println("undefined");
                              }else{
                                  System.out.println("\n" + userarr[i].username);
                              };
                          }
                     } else if (ch3.equals("back")) {
                         break;
                     } else {
                          for (int i=0;i<a;i++) {
                              if ((userarr[i].username).equals(ch3)){
                                  System.out.println("type the password for this account (USE NUMBERS ONLY).");
                                  int ch4 = scan.nextInt();
                                  if (ch4==userarr[i].password) {
                                      a --;
                                      userarr[i] = null;
                                      System.out.println("user deleted!");
                                      break;
                                  }else{
                                      System.out.println("incorrect password.");
                                      break;
                                  }

                              }else if (i==a-1) { 
                                  System.out.println("user not found.");
                                  break;
                              }

                          }

                     } 
                 }else {
                     System.out.println("Initializing user creation method:");
                     newuser();
                 }
                 break;
             case "log":
                 login();
                 break;
             case "exit":
                 System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                 System.exit(0);
                 break;
             case "debug":
                 for (int i=0;i<userarr.length;i++) {
                     System.out.println(userarr[i]);
                 }
                 break;
             default:
                 System.out.println("restarting.");
         }

     } while (true);
 } 

}//Note from other user - Extra bracket?
```

Comment: Which line is TextGame:80? Have you attached a debugger and stepped through it? NullPointers are usually pretty straightforward.

Comment: You didn't supply enough information. However, the error tells you exactly what and where the issue is. `at text.game.TextGame.loggedin(TextGame.java:80)` Line 80 of TextGame.java. A `NullPointerException` indicates that something on that line is not initialized.

Comment: that is the line i was talking about that has the problem, userarr[login].notes[b] = tempnote;

Comment: what;s the scan object? what is it's data type?

Comment: i don't know. its a java utility i imported with import java.util.Scanner;. it lets the user type in stuff.

Comment: At what point did you add a new user to the userarr? Where is that code?

Comment: i added the whole class in the question so you can have all the information necessary to make an accurate analysis of the issue.

Comment: i think you might have an extra bracket at your login button. It's hard to tell  due to the formatting and length of the code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
String[] notes;
```

to something like:

```
String[] notes = new String[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you don't appear to be checking if there are next lines/ints whenever you use your scanner's next functions.

Take these two lines from your code for example...

```
String ch2 = scan.nextLine();

int ch4 = scan.nextInt();
```

You can check if there is indeed a next int, or next line by using the hasNext functions...

```
String ch2; //Declared outside of the if-statement for scope reasons
if(scan.hasNextLine()){
    //the hasNext functions return true if there is a next line (or int for hasNextInt).
    ch2 = scan.nextLine();
}else{
    //if something needs to be done in the event that there is no nextLine, do it here
}

int ch4;
if(scan.hasNextInt()){
    ch4 = scan.hasNextInt();
}else{
    //if something needs to be done in the event that there is no nextInt, do it here
}
```

This might not solve your issue; however, this at least can prevent many potential issues later. You should always be sure there is more content to get before you get it, and using the hasNext functions make it very easy.

See more at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html